# Jquery function for add and remove class with setTimeout function for multiple ids

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Below is the jQuery code where I want to create a jQuery function for toast message, but first block of code working means add class, but `setTimeout` and click on close class not working.

**jQuery**

```
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }, 3000);
        
        $('.close').on("click", function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active'); 
        });
    });
}

$('#click').on("click", function () {
    $('#toast').myplugin();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="click">Click me</button>
<div class="toast-msg success-toast" id="toast">
    <p>
        Request
        <strong>#124245374</strong>
        sent successfully!
        <span class="close"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing comes from the fact that you are losing the reference to `this` when you are calling it inside the internal functions because it is being re-assigned. You can checkout this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to learn more.

The solution is to use arrow functions to keep the reference to `this` pointing to your `#toast` div.

The working example below showcases the solution with a `.active` class that turns the div's background green.

```js
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");

        // use arrow function here
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }, 3000);

        // use arrow function here
        $('.close').on("click", () => {
            $(this).removeClass('active'); 
        });
    });
}
$('#click').on("click", function () {
    $('#toast').myplugin();
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: green;
}
.close {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
<div class="toast-msg success-toast" id="toast">
    <p>
        Request
        <strong>#124245374</strong>
        sent successfully!
        <span class="close">Close</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

***Alternate Solution***

Since older browsers (such as Internet Explorer 10 and below) do not offer support for arrow functions, another approach is to save the reference to the current div in a variable that the inner functions can access, this is possible because the variable is defined in the context where the function was created.

```js
$.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var thisDiv = $(this);
        thisDiv.addClass("active");

        setTimeout(function () {
            thisDiv.removeClass("active");
        }, 3000);

        $('.close').on("click", function () {
            thisDiv.removeClass('active'); 
        });
    });
}
$('#click').on("click", function () {
    $('#toast').myplugin();
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: green;
}
.close {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click me</button>
<div class="toast-msg success-toast" id="toast">
    <p>
        Request
        <strong>#124245374</strong>
        sent successfully!
        <span class="close">Close</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ghassen for help, it's work fine in crome but not working in ie10 and plus becoz ie does not support arrow function, can you help me with ie support solution plz?

Comment: Sure, there you go.

Comment: Thank you so much Ghassen. it's works fine. world is better becoz of you people.

Comment: Glad I could help!